# How to update MPNowPlayingInfoCenter in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mpnowplayinginfocenter

In objective c, I've been using code like this to update MPNowPlayingInfoCenter:

```
[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo: 
    @{ MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : @"Artist!",
        MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : @"Title! }];
```

But in Swift, it doesn't seem like the function "setNowPlayingInfo" is recognized:

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter()....  // Can't identify 'setNowPlayingInfo()'
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: try `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : "Artist!",  MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : "Title!]`, setters/getters behave quite differently in Swift from ObjC

Comment: @JackWu thanks so much. Yep, still getting the hang of Swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift, getters/setters work differently. Since there are no more properties like in ObjC, there are no automatically generated setters/getters for you. You should just access the variable directly.

In your case, use:

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : "Artist!",  MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : "Title!"]
```

Comment: As of today, i can't get it to work... get a error 

**type "String" does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'**

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2, this also work:

```
let songInfo: [String:AnyObject] = [
         MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: mySoundTrack.TrackName,
         MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: String(mySoundTrack.TrackID),
         MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: albumArt
]

MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = songInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer by @Jack no longer works as is, and needs some modifications.

Swift 3 compiler complains about 2 things.

- String is not directly convertible to AnyObject, and so the two dictionary entry values must be casted from String to AnyObject.
- `defaultCenter()` has been renamed to `default()`.

so a viable code will look like this:

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : "Artist!" as AnyObject,  MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : "Title!" as AnyObject]
```